Account_link (pending) In network
I am trying to create a onboarding process for my webisite via Stripe connect. When I pass endpoints through my index.tsx buttons one seems to work and the other one just says status pending and they are almost the same thing. It is not Fetching the /api/account_link I know this because I reversed debugged it and also deleted the /api/account_link and it still said pending, which should give me a 500 error but did not (which is how I know it is not reaching the Fetch /api/account_link. Here are the files please help me!!
Index.tsx:
"use client";

import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
const \[accountCreatePending, setAccountCreatePending\] = useState(false);
const \[accountLinkCreatePending, setAccountLinkCreatePending\] =
useState(false);
const \[error, setError\] = useState(false);
const \[connectedAccountId, setConnectedAccountId\] = useState();

console.log("connectedAccountId:", connectedAccountId); // Log connectedAccountId state

return (
\<div className="container"\>
\<div className="banner"\>

<h2>Dream Marketplace</h2>
\
\
{!connectedAccountId && <h2>Get ready for take off</h2>}
{!connectedAccountId && (
<p>
Dream Marketplace is the world's leading air travel platform: join
our team of pilots to help people travel faster.
</p>
)}
{connectedAccountId && (
<h2>Add information to start accepting money</h2>
)}
{connectedAccountId && (
<p>
Matt's Mats partners with Stripe to help you receive payments while
keeping your personal and bank details secure.
</p>
)}
{!accountCreatePending && !connectedAccountId && (
\<button
onClick={async () =\> {
setAccountCreatePending(true);
setError(false);
console.log("Creating account..."); // Log action
fetch("/api/account", {
method: "POST",
})
.then((response) =\> response.json())
.then((json) =\> {
setAccountCreatePending(false);
console.log("Account creation response:", json); // Log response

                  const { account, error } = json;
    
                  if (account) {
                    setConnectedAccountId(account);
                    console.log("Account created, ID:", account); // Log account ID
                  }
    
                  if (error) {
                    setError(true);
                    console.log("Error in account creation:", error); // Log error
                  }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                  setAccountCreatePending(false);
                  setError(true);
                  console.error("Fetch error:", err); // Log fetch error
                });
            }}
          >
            Create an account!
          </button>
        )}
        {connectedAccountId && !accountLinkCreatePending && (
          <button
            onClick={async () => {
              setAccountLinkCreatePending(true);
              setError(false);
              console.log("Creating account link..."); // Log action
              fetch("/api/account_link", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                  account: connectedAccountId,
                }),
              })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((json) => {
                  setAccountLinkCreatePending(false);
                  console.log("Account link response:", json); // Log response
    
                  const { url, error } = json;
                  if (url) {
                    console.log("Redirecting to URL:", url); // Log URL
                    window.location.href = url;
                  }
    
                  if (error) {
                    setError(true);
                    console.log("Error in account link creation:", error); // Log error
                  }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                  setAccountLinkCreatePending(false);
                  setError(true);
                  console.error("Fetch error:", err); // Log fetch error
                });
            }}
          >
            Add information
          </button>
        )}
        {error && <p className="error">Something went wrong!</p>}
        {(connectedAccountId ||
          accountCreatePending ||
          accountLinkCreatePending) && (
          <div className="dev-callout">
            {connectedAccountId && (
              <p>
                Your connected account ID is:{" "}
                <code className="bold">{connectedAccountId}</code>
              </p>
            )}
            {accountCreatePending && <p>Creating a connected account...</p>}
            {accountLinkCreatePending && <p>Creating a new Account Link...</p>}
          </div>
        )}
        <div className="info-callout">
          <p>
            This is a sample app for Stripe-hosted Connect onboarding.{" "}
            <a
              href="https://docs.stripe.com/connect/onboarding/quickstart?connect-onboarding-surface=hosted"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
            >
              View docs
            </a>
          </p>``your text``
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

);
}


account_link.ts (create Account Link Endpoint):
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { stripe } from "@/lib/stripe";

export default async function handler(
req: NextApiRequest,
res: NextApiResponse
) {
console.log("Received request:", req.method, req.body);

if (req.method === "POST") {
try {
const { account } = req.body;
console.log("Creating account link for account:", account);

      const accountLink = await stripe.accountLinks.create({
        account: account,
        refresh_url: `${req.headers.origin}/refresh/${account}`,
        return_url: `${req.headers.origin}/return/${account}`,
        type: "account_onboarding",
      });
    
      console.log("Account link created:", accountLink.url);
      res.status(200).json({ url: accountLink.url });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating account link:", error);
      //@ts-expect-error
      res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    }

} else {
res.status(405).json({ error: "Method not allowed" });
}``
}

I have tried pretty much everything from the moon and back. Ive explained some of what I have tried above noting seems to work.
